# Command that outputs script results into a text file then emails results to personal email

Tags: linux, bash, shell, email, server

I am writing a bash script that outputs server status results and want to have a way for it to put the results into a text file then email it to an email entered depending on user input. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please do something about the indentation and post a minimum example with all irrelevant stuff removed.

Comment: "I want to add the mentioned action to the last section where it says output results into text file" Your question should be this, just that. Not a full on copy of everything else that does work and has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Okay, I removed the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to output the results to a file, use the >> or > to at the end of your command followed by a file name.

>> will append to the file. Which means the previous content of your file will remain intact.

> will remove everything and create a file with the new ouput.

for eg:
echo $serverOutput>output.txt

now to mail it :
read email   // will read the email address of the user.

to mail:

uuencode output.txt output.txt|mailx -s "server output" $email

your file will be sent as an attachment.

Is this what you require?

Comment: sorry to bother again, so what would an example of the whole code look like for this?

Comment: I want to basically do it where it asks the user for their email and creates a cron job for that email and sends it after the script runs

Comment: added another answer, Comments limiting the number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a cron job would be another task. But for your initial question about having the serverStatus inside a text file and then mail that to the user's email. Below is an example:

say we use "ps -ef|grep processname" command. replace "top" with the command you have.

ssh -q username@serverName "ps -ef|grep -i process">>output.txt

echo "enter email:"

read email

uuencode output.txt output.txt|mailx -s "serverStatusReport" $email

if you have any script/template which needs to be given this functionality, please share the code or elaborate a bit.
Regarding the cron job you would need to include the command/script in the crontab file along with the time you want it to schedule.

for eg:

echo "* * * * * /path/to/your/script.sh ">>crontab

Hope this gives you a path forward on your task